# Powershell script to get number of lists, list items, libraries, and documents in a given sharepoint online site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I just started using PowerShell 4 days ago, so this may just be a simple syntax issue I'm not understanding. I have some code that I've cobbled together here:

```
#sharepoint site url
$Site = Get-SPOSite https://______________________ 

#variables
$CountDocumentItems = 0
$CountDocumentLibray = 0
$CountListItems = 0
$CountList = 0
$Results = @()

#Get Credentials to connect to SharePoint Admin Center
$Cred = Get-Credential

Function Get-SPOWeb($WebURL){    
    
    #Setup credentials to connect    
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)    
    
    #Get Web information and subsites    
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebURL)    
    $Context.Credentials = $Credentials    
    $Web = $Context.Web    
    $Context.Load($Web)    
    $Context.Load($Web.Webs)    
    $Context.executeQuery()    
    
    #Iterate through each subsite in the current web    
    foreach ($Subweb in $Web.Webs)    {        
        #Get the web object        
        $Subweb        
        
        #Call the function recursively to process all subsites underneath the current web        
        Get-SPOWeb($Subweb.url)    
    }
}

$AllWebs = Get-SPOWeb $Site.Url
foreach ($item in $AllWebs) {
    
    foreach($list in $item.Lists) {
        if ($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {          
            $CountDocumentLibray = $CountDocumentLibray + 1
            $CountDocumentItems = $list.ItemCount + $CountDocumentItems
        }
        else {
            $CountList = $CountList+1
            $CountListItems = $list.ItemCount + $CountListItems
        }
    }
    $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Site Title' = $item.Title 
        'Document Library Count' = $CountDocumentLibray
        'Document Count' = $CountDocumentItems
        'List Count' = $CountList
        'List Item Count' = $CountListItems 
    }
    $CountDocumentItems = 0
    $CountDocumentLibray = 0
    $CountListItems = 0
    $CountList = 0
}
#$site.Dispose()
$Results | Select 'Site Title', 'Document Library Count', 'Document Count', 'List Count', 'List Item Count' | Format-Table
```

When I run it, it does not like the `foreach($list in $item.Lists)` line at all. I get alternating "The collection has not been initialized" errors with `$list` or `$item.Lists` being underlined. I've tried setting `$item.Lists` into a variable and looping through that variable with the same issue. When I just type `$item.` inside the first foreach it does give me `Lists` as an option. I am not really sure where to go from here.

That whole foreach section came from someone trying to demonstrate looping through an SP site, not SPO, so perhaps I'm just trying to use the wrong properties entirely. But I don't know enough yet to understand what it is I do need.

*Editing to add that after a whole bunch of that same error in a row, I do get a table output with the list of site titles, so `$item.Title` seems to be working fine. But all the counts are 0 because nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

-Added the line `$Context.Load($Web.Lists)` under the line `$Context.Load($Web.Webs)`

-Added these three lines under the line `$Subweb`

```
$Context.Load($Subweb)
$Context.Load($Subweb.Lists)
$Context.executeQuery()
```

I'm not sure which line/lines did it; I just added what it wanted until the code worked and I'll have to experiment later with commenting out things and seeing if all 4 of those lines are necessary. But there you have it. The code works!